Complete several Tasks in a specific order
I have an WPF application that collects and prints multiple pdf files in a specific order to a online printer. The problem is that it is taking very long time, one page takes about 10sec and the full process is up to 10min.
I have tried to start all tasks and then await Task.WhenAll but then it doesnt get in the order i have created and started the task due to some files bigger than others and gets completed and sent to printer before.
I would like to start all printjobs (Printdocument) and before EndPrint event is triggered (gets sent to que) wait for tasks started earlier to finnish before next task in line can complete. Tried to listen to PagePrint event and when HasMorePages == false, await the task with index-1 but doesnt get it to work. Someone that have had an similar problem and have a solution for this?
foreach(var file in files)
    PrintJob(file);

public static void PrintJob(File file)
{
    var doc = file.PdfDocument.GetPrintDocument(SettingsPrinter.DefaultSettings);
    doc.Print();
}


updated post with short code.
using Ironpdf and System.Drawing.Printing

You gain more control by querying and managing the print queues yourself (System.Printing namespace). "Provides classes that enable you to automate the management of print servers, print queues, and print jobs."

I have tried using System.Printing, but the queue's NumberOfJobs is 0 even though I know there are files in the queue.

I assume that the call to file.PdfDocument.GetPrintDocument(SettingsPrinter.DefaultSettings) is slow and the Print() call cannot be made faster?

GetPrintDocument goes fast 0,015 sec for one exempel file. I believe it is the render that takes time as the time per page is about 10 sec.

@Rekan  _printServer = new PrintServer();
_printQueue = new PrintQueue(_printServer, _printerQueueName,
PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter );
foreach ( PrintSystemJobInfo job in _printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection() ) {...}

@GerrySchmitz I still dont get the jobs in que. Probably due to online printer i guess.

The "queue name" has to match something you can identify. Start with a "local" printer to get the mechanics down. I could present my "spooler", but that would be "off topic".
